# Can a sequence of functions $(f_n(x))_n$ converge uniformly AND can there be an unbounded member $f_N(x)$ for an $N\in\mathbb{N}$ at the same time?

Tags: real-analysis

Assuming $f_n: D\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ converges uniformly against $f:D\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, then for every $\epsilon >0$ there is a $K\in\mathbb{N}$, so that for every $n\geq K$ and $x\in\mathbb{R}$: $|f_n(x)-f(x)|<\epsilon$

Could an $N\in\mathbb{N}$ exist, so that $f_N(x)$ is unbounded?
If so, can you give me an example?

Thoughts:

Case 1 - $f$ is bounded:
Assuming that $f_N$ is unbounded.
It is clear, that $N\leq K$, because otherwise $|f_N(x)-f(x)|< \epsilon $ for every $x\in D$, but then $f_N(x)<f(x)+\epsilon < \sup\{f(x)| x\in D\} + \epsilon$ would also be true for every $x\in D$, which would be a contradiction to the assumption that $f_N(x)$ is unbounded.

So if such an $N$ exists, $N<K$ must apply.

Case 2 - $f$ is unbounded:
In this case I think that $f_N$ must be unbounded for $N\geq K$.

Assuming that $f_N$ is bounded with $N\geq K$, then $s=\sup\{|f_N(x)|| x\in D\}$ exists, but $f(x)$ is unbounded, so for every real Number $s$ exists an $x\in D$, so that $|f(x)|>|s|+2$.
Set $\epsilon =1$, it follows:

$\epsilon=1>|f(x)-f_N(x)|\geq |f(x)|-|f_N(x)|\geq |f(x)|-|s| > 2  $, which is a contradiction.

So $f_N$ must be unbounded for $N\geq K$.

I think for case 2 I answered my own question, but I'm not sure about case 1 for $N<K$.

Comment: One unbounded member isn’t going to affect anything…

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take $D=\Bbb R$ and$$\begin{array}{rccc}f_n\colon&D&\longrightarrow&\Bbb R\\&x&\mapsto&\begin{cases}x&\text{ if }n=1\\0&\text{ otherwise.}\end{cases}\end{array}$$Then $(f_n)_{n\in\Bbb N}$ converges uniformly to the null function. However, $f_1$ is unbounded.

On the other hand, if a sequence $(f_n)_{n\in\Bbb N}$ of function converges uniformly to a bounded function, then there is some $N\in\Bbb N$ such that $f_n$ is bounded when $n\geqslant N$.